# Incorrectly receiving chat flags

Tags: support, chat

I just got a pop-up about a comment being flagged as offensive.

Weird thing is, I've never been in that room, and I'm therefore not an owner of the room. I'm also not a mod - was this a glitch?

[image]

Comment: Chat flags are shown to >10k users, regardless of whether they are room owners or moderators or which room the flag was raised.

Comment: aah, never seen one before so had no idea! Is there a page I should read somewhere to prevent further embarassment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chat flags are shown to users having more than 10k of reputation, regardless of whether they are room owners, moderators or which room the flag was raised.

You can read more about chat privileges [on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87761/is-there-a-list-of-se-chat-privileges-and-the-minimum-reputation-required-for-t):

> The privilege levels are: [...]
>
> - 10k rep:
>
>   1. be notified of spam/offensive flags (the number of active flags appears in a circle on your gravatar)
>   2. view frozen and deleted rooms (read access only if allowed).